# IMPORTRANGE returning NO_COLUMN

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language, importrange

I am using:

```
=query(importrange(SHEETID,"Orders!$A$2:$X"),"select Col1 where Col23=0")
```

in a Google Sheets and receiving the following error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col23"

I have authorized the IMPORTRANGE already and it will import that data correctly when used without the query.

Any ideas as to what is causing this error?

Comment: Create a demo spreadsheet, share it with anyone with the link and include it on the question. Reference: [mcve].

Comment: Alright I'll do that right now

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ) before the select like this:

```
=query(importrange("1_WqEDk9_XKakYVdzIm0eahWpBrY4-55ez4gauolMdAo","Sheet1!$A$2:$X","select Col1 where Col23=0")
```

Comment: This looks the same. I don't know what ) you removed.